# How to repackage a dependency with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to remove some duplicate classes from this library:

```
org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.14
```

How should I repackage it with Android Studio?

**Edit**

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/ReferenceResolver;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLEvent;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLInputStream;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLName;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLStreamException;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable$Util;
Error:8 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Is it your artifact ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan No, it belongs to apache. Though I have the license to modify it.

Comment: @Ozuf Edit your question to show your error, so i may be able to give a more precise answer, checkout my answer.

Comment: @Distjoy I jave added the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it really depends on how you plan to add it...

if you add it as an online repository you need to add the repository to the build.gradle file under the app folder and add it to the dependencies

otherwise as a project you can add it to the project folder and then to the dependencies and under the settings gradle add it as an include...

check out the pictures...  you can see that i have several online repositories that i am drawing dependencies from and one that has been added as a project contained within the file system...

[image: adding repositories to the online fetch with dependencies at the bottom]

[image: adding an included project as a dependency in the settings gradle]

here paho has been added from an online respository
and deckview from a project contained in the app file structure

Comment: I plan to add it to my project as a module. I have tried adding it as an online repo but the error keeps coming up. I have read somewhere that tika always have problem compiling on Android, that the best solution is to repackage it and remove the duplicate classes.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the package name of the classes that has already been imported, just add this in the dependency section of app level gradle file

```
compile('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.14'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
}
```